# MongoDB StitchClient cannot be accessed inside a js function

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

I have already called stClient.login function inside  "addUser()" and "loginUser()" and they worked pretty well. I am able to add the user to my MongoDB database and find the user when login clicked. (dont bother with delete one) After finding a logged user in DB, i am loading a new HTML page where i pass the name of the logged user and profil photo retrieved from MongoDB. Besides, i also want to display the comments of the logged user along with the name and profil photo. Here the issue comes: in showComments method, i am not able to access the stitch Client. Any help is so much appreciated. 
Below is the code:

**Html 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>myFb</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
    <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/library/v3/stable/stitch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assig02.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="onLoadConnectDB()">


<p>Hello My App</p>

<div id="wlcom" align="center">
    <button name="adding" onclick="addUser()">Add User</button><br>
    <button name="deleting" onclick="deleteUser()">Delete User</button> <br>
    <button name="logging" onclick="loginUser()">Login</button><br>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Common JS for 2 HTMLs:**

```
let db;
    let itemsCollection;
    let stClient;
    let globalName;
    let temp;

     let clientPromise = stitch.StitchClientFactory.create('facebookclone-tlwvi');

    function onLoadConnectDB(){
        clientPromise.then(stitchClient=>{
            stClient=stitchClient;
            db = stClient.service('mongodb', 'mongodb-atlas').db('FbUsers');
            itemsCollection=db.collection("ClonedFbUsers");
        });

    }

function addUser(){
    var n= prompt("Your username: ")
    const userId = stClient.authedId();
    stClient.login().then(()=>
        itemsCollection.insertOne({ owner_id: stClient.authedId(), userName : n , profilePhoto: "https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/115/115265.png", photos: ["NULL"],comments: [{msg:"NULL",time:"NULL",like:0}] })
        ).then(() => itemsCollection.find({}).execute())
    .then(docs =>
      docs.forEach((doc, index) =>
        console.log(`${index}: ${JSON.stringify(doc)}`)
        )
      );
 // });
    alert("added");
}

function deleteUser(){

    var d= prompt("Username to delete: ");
    const userId = stClient.authedId();
    stClient.login().then(()=>
        itemsCollection.deleteOne({ userName: "Messi" })
        ).then(() => itemsCollection.find({}).execute())
    .then(docs =>
      docs.forEach((doc, index) =>
        console.log(`${index}: ${JSON.stringify(doc)}`)
        )
      );
    alert("User "+d+ " deleted.");


}

function loginUser(){
var n= prompt("Your username: ");
globalName=n;
    const userId = stClient.authedId();
    try{
    stClient.login().then(()=>

         itemsCollection.find({ userName : n }).execute()
        ).then(docs=>

        loadUser(n,docs.map(c=>c.userName),docs.map(c=>c.profilePhoto)) //found result in db, send userName and pp link while loading a new user
        );

}catch(err){
    alert("not found a user");
}

 // });
}
function loadUser(name,usName,pp){
if(usName!=""||usName!=null){
//sending name and profile photo link retrieved form db to 2nd HTML
    document.location = "user.html?name="+encodeURIComponent(usName)+"&prof="+encodeURIComponent(pp);
    //document.getElementById("name").value=name;
}else{
    //no user in db
    alert(name+ " is not found");
}

}
 function onLoad () {
    //onLoadConnectDB();

    var pic;
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('name').value = data.name;
    document.getElementById('pp').src=decodeURIComponent(data.prof);
    showComments(data.name);

   // document.getElementById('pp').value=data.pp;
}

 function showComments(globalName){

//ISSUE IS HERE!!

        stClient.login().then(()=>

         itemsCollection.find({ userName : globalName }).execute()
        ).then(docs=>


        document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = docs.map(c => "<div>" + c.comments + "</div>").join("")
        );
        };
```

**HTML2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyProfile</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
     <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/library/v3/stable/stitch.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assig02.js"></script>
</head>


  <header>
  <div class="Header">
  <div class="search">
    <img src="white.png" >
</div>
    <div class="profile curs">
    <img src="me+.png">
    <span class="barr" >     &nbsp &nbsp Home </span><span> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp<img src="frndd.png"> &nbsp <img src="messengerr.png"> <img src="notf.png" style=""> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <img src="secret.png"></span>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </header> 


<body onload="onLoad()">
<img id = "pp" src="" width="50" height="50">
<p> <input style="border: none; font-size: 20px; width: 100%" id="name" type="text" readonly></p>


<button type="submit" onclick="addPhoto()">Add Photo</button> <br>
<button type="submit">Choose Profile Photo</button><br>

<div class="comments" id="comments" onclick ="showComments()">
Show comments


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but what does HTML1 and HTML2 have to do with this? Are you actually reloading this full HTML and scripts into the browser? And then are we to then follow that you don't actually instantiate the stitch client in both? Because I only see `onLoadConnectDB()` **ONCE**. And it really looks like you are loading everything in completely separate http requests. You can't do that.

Comment: I previously added onLoadConnectDB() function inside onLoad() function and it didnt help either.  i just want to open user html (2nd html) when a user enters its login name and pass the name and profil photo to that html.

Comment: If you have a completely separate http request ( not XhttpRequest ) which loads a "full" HTML page completely, then you must **establish all run code, including authentication and authorization again**. When you "reload" in such a way, all code you have previously executed looses it's "state". This is exactly why in the modern world we build **S**ingle **P**age **A**pplications ( SPA ) instead of this very antiquated approach of loading a remote HTML page completely.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would you suggest to load a new page with retrieved data displaying on it?  i separated JS file for the second HTML where i do connection again but it is so frustrating to see that it still cannot recognize stitch client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is relating to async/sync communication. After separating js for html2, i was calling onLoad2() function inside onLoad() function after assuming the connection is established, but no. Should 'wait' till the connection is established and then call another function. js2:

```
    let db;
    let itemsCollection;
    let stClient;
    let globalName;
    let temp;

    let clientPromise = stitch.StitchClientFactory.create('facebookclone-tlwvi');


function onLoad(){

        clientPromise.then(stitchClient=>{
            stClient=stitchClient;
            db = stClient.service('mongodb', 'mongodb-atlas').db('FbUsers');
            itemsCollection=db.collection("ClonedFbUsers");
            onLoad2(); //if you call outside then, wont work. onLoad2() will be interpreted before establishing connection to db


        });
    }


     function onLoad2 () {
    var pic;
    var url = window.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('name').value = data.name;
    document.getElementById('pp').src=decodeURIComponent(data.prof);
    showComments(data.name);

}

 function showComments(globalName){
    console.log("i am here");
    const userId = stClient.authedId();

        stClient.login().then(()=>

         itemsCollection.find({ userName : globalName }).execute()
        ).then(docs=>


        document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = docs.map(c => "<div>" + c.comments.msg + "</div>").join(" ")
        );
        }


   function addComment(){

    var n=document.getElementById("name").value;

    var com= document.getElementById("comment").value
   stClient.login().then(()=>
        itemsCollection.updateOne({userName : n}, {$push:{comments:{msg:com,time:"22:30",like:4}}})
        ).then(() => itemsCollection.find({}).execute())
    .then(docs =>
      docs.forEach((doc, index) =>
        console.log(`${index}: ${JSON.stringify(doc)}`)
        )
      );

   }
```

HTML for the js2:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyProfile</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
     <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/library/v3/stable/stitch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assig022.js"></script>
</head>


  <header>
  <div class="Header">
  <div class="search">
    <img src="white.png" >
</div>
    <div class="profile curs">
    <img src="me+.png">
    <span class="barr" >     &nbsp &nbsp Home </span><span> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp<img src="frndd.png"> &nbsp <img src="messengerr.png"> <img src="notf.png" style=""> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <img src="secret.png"></span>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </header> 


<body onload="onLoad()">
<img id = "pp" src="" width="50" height="50">
<p> <input style="border: none; font-size: 20px; width: 100%" id="name" type="text" readonly></p>


<button type="submit" onclick="addPhoto()">Add Photo</button> <br>
<button type="submit">Choose Profile Photo</button><br>

<div class="comments" id="comments">
</div>
<br>


    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Type comment">
    <button onclick="addComment()">Send</button>

</body>
</html>
```